Jamshidian's formulation of Black Derman Toy
In his 1991 paper on forward induction of binomial tree calibration on BDT model, it is stated that
$$r(t) = U(t)\exp(\sigma(t)W(t))$$
where $r$ is the short rate modelled by Black Derman Toy. It is further stated that $U$ above is the median of short rate distribution at time $t$. Now if I recall correctly, in BDT model the short rate is modelled as
$$d\log(r(t)) = \left[\theta(t) - \frac{\sigma'(t)}{\sigma(t)}\log(r(t))\right]dt + \sigma(t)dW$$
Now I can see that $r(t)$ might be put into the form above, but how is the claim that $U(t)$ being the median is justified?
After some google searches, I can't seem to find a reference for this.

It suffices to prove $\mathbb{P}(r(t) \ge U(t))=\frac{1}{2}$ which is true because
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(r(t) \ge U(t))&=\mathbb{P}(\exp{\sigma(t)W(t)} \ge 1) = \mathbb{P}(W(t) \ge 0) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$
